# npm install in Jenkins Pipeline not Working (Webpack-Project)

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm, webpack, jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkins pipeline and a NPM/Webpack project. My Jenkins server is running on a Windows Server 2016 1607 - I got the newest Jenkins release.

I want to deploy the project via Jenkins.

One of the first steps is, to install the dependencies:

```
            echo "Run Webpack"
            dir("static") {
                bat "npm install"

                echo "Build for Dev"
                bat "npm run build:dev"
            }
```

When the pipeline is at this step there is a loop and i dont see a progress or something like that:

[image]

I can wait for 30 minutes and there appears nothing. I dont know what to do.

Note: When i go via cmd to this path and run "npm install" everything works fine. This is only a problem with Jenkins.

I hope that someone knows a workaround or have an idea how to do this in another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved:** Sorry for the question. Now after a few tries npm throws an error message. The problem was, that my server wasn't able to connect to the internet through our firewall.

I never thaught that this was the problem because on the local machine "npm install" works. But on the local machine it seems that NPM used our proxy server. That was the reason why it works locally and not with jenkins.